# Sort using count and sum with variables XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to make a sort with "Average Goals Score" for each place using sum and count with variables:

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rugby.xsl"?>

<rugby>
    <games>
        <game>
            <place>USA</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>20-1</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>USA</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>2-20</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>USA</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>24-11</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>USA</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>12-41</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>USA</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>20-100</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>Mexico</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>1-32</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>Mexico</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>2-100</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>Peru</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>2-10</score>
        </game>
        <game>
            <place>Peru</place>
            <team1>Team1</team1>
            <team1>Team2</team1>
            <score>100-2</score>
        </game>
    </games>
</rugby>
```

And XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/rugby">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_style.css" type="text/css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Place</td>
                        <td>Average Goals Score</td>
                        <td>Average Goals Conceded</td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:variable name="numOfGames" select="count(//games/game)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//games/game/place">
                        <xsl:variable name="nameOfPlace" select="text()"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="score" select="sum(//games/game/place[contains(., $nameOfPlace)]/following-sibling::score/number(substring-before(.,'-')))"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="conceded" select="sum(//games/game/place[contains(., $nameOfPlace)]/following-sibling::score/number(substring-after(.,'-')))"/>

                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="place"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="$score div $numOfGames"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="$conceded div $numOfGames"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was tring to make the sort after variables:

```
<xsl:sort select="$score div $numOfGames" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
```

But it doesn't work because the sort has to be under the for each (and I have to create the variables first). I've tried to remove the variables sum and count but I can't remove variable nameOfPlace, so the sort will not work at all.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//games/game/place">
                        <xsl:variable name="nameOfPlace" select=""/>
                        <xsl:sort select="sum(//games/game/place[contains(., $nameOfPlace)]/following-sibling::score/number(substring-before(.,'-'))) div count(//games/game)" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="place"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(//games/game/place[contains(., $nameOfPlace)]/following-sibling::score/number(substring-before(.,'-'))) div count(//games/game)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(//games/game/place[contains(., $nameOfPlace)]/following-sibling::score/number(substring-after(.,'-'))) div count(//games/game)"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! So far, the problem description is clear. It is irritating that you're not allowed to use `variable` statements before the `sort`. Now, in order for us to help determine why the sort doesn't work when you do it without variables, you'll need to show us that code, and specify how it doesn't work (how does the output differ from what you expected?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it *with* variables is to declare the variables inside the XPath expression using `for`:

```
<xsl:sort select="for $nameOfPlace in text(),
      $score in sum(//games/game/place[contains(., $nameOfPlace)]/
                     following-sibling::score/number(substring-before(.,'-')))
        return $score div $numOfGames"
   order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
```

Something like that. (Untested.)

Yeah, it's clunky. And 
unfortunately those variables then wouldn't be available outside the XPath expression. So you'd have to declare them again if you want to use them after the sort. It's up to you whether the above is an improvement over doing it without variables.

**Update:**
In regard to doing it *without* variables.

You were having trouble figuring out how to remove the `nameOfPlace` variable declaration. How about this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//games/game/place">
  <xsl:sort select="sum(//games/game/place[contains(., current()/text())]/
        following-sibling::score/number(substring-before(.,'-')))
      div count(//games/game)"
    order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
```

`current()` allows you to refer to whatever the context item is *outside* the current XPath expression (the `sort` `select`). In this case, that would be the `<place>` element that the `<xsl:-for-each>` is iterating over.